# How to traverse the data in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to access the **name** having the value **correspond** and **abc** through angularjs.

How to access **name** field inside Data>Tag1>firebase_Key1>name.

My data is in below format.

```
"Data":
    {
    "Tag1":
    {
    "-KXtD3TQbHQqU2KnKeyw":
     {
     "name":"correspond",
     "addressLine1":"xyz",
     "mobile":"989923232"
     }
    }
    {
    "-KXtD3TQbHQqU2KnKeop":
     {
     "name":"abc",
     "addressLine1":"xyz",
     "mobile":"9121121212"
     }
    }
    }
```

Comment: What you have tried so far? Or try creating a plunker demo

Comment: `for(var key in Data.Tag1){alert Data.Tag1[key].name}`. This is fairly basic javascript, it's not related to angularJS.